# RewriteMap problem in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, rewritemap

I need to redirect URLs of the form subpage.php?sid=123 to named pages.

subpagemap.txt exists in the root and contains just the following delimited by Unix line endings \n:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

The .htaccess is as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteMap subpagemap txt:subpagemap.txt
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} subpage\.php\?sid=([0-9]*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ ${subpagemap:%1|home}? [R=301,L,NC]
```

The problem is that I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error.

When I comment out line 4 of the .htaccess, line 5 works fine and I get redirected to the default map - /home, which suggests it's the map file that's the problem.

As soon as I put the RewriteMap line back in, I get a 500 Internal Server error. I don't have access to the server logs and RewriteLog doesn't seem to work at all.

I have also tried the following substitutions one by one and together to try to isolate the problem:

```
RewriteMap subpagemap txt:/subpagemap.txt
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} subpage\.php\?sid=([0-9]*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ /${subpagemap:1|home} [R=301,L,NC]
```

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Next questions to ask: is subpagemap.txt in the location that RewriteMap expects to find it? Have you used an absolutely pathname. Next, can you view the Apache error_log to determine why the 500 Internal Server Error was generated?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, even if the servers supports it, the problem is that you are trying do define the RewriteMap in a per-directory context (e.g. in .htaccess file), which is not allowed: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteMap

Move the definition to server or virtual host configuration, and it should work.

I still realize you probably have figured it out in a year and a half :)

Answer (score 1):

I found that the answer was that the server host doesn't support RewriteMap.

That wasted a good 5 hours or so of debug.

Comment: RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel are your friends ;)